# Subclass as a collection of classes

Tags: design-patterns, inheritance

In Java we could have (assume extra constructor methods, etc):

```
class Car
{
    public void Vrooom() { System.out.print("Vrooom!"); }
}

class Prius extends Car
{
    public void Vrooom() { System.out.print("..."); }
}

class Cars extends Car
{
    private ArrayList<Car> mCars;
    public void Vrooom() { for(Car car: mCars) car.Vrooom(); }
}
```

I came across code doing something like this, but `Cars` doesn't feel right to me, as it has to override every single `Car` method to add the `for` loop. Is this an anti-pattern, and if so, why should I not do this?

Comment: Inheritance is supposed to represent an is-a relationship.  You wouldn't normally say that an array of cars is-a car.

Comment: I agree with @VaughnCato, normally you'd extend your `Cars` class from an array type (or whatever the equivalent java class is), or just use a generic list in its place (if you didn't need a strongly-typed representation with helper methods, etc.). Also, for why you *shouldn't* do it, by extending `Car` there's nothing stopping you from adding a `Cars` to your list. After all, you're saying "Cars is a Car."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are inheriting a car to represent a list of cars? You don't need to do this. If you simply want a list of cars, then you can create

```
List<Car> list = new ArrayList<Car>();
```

Inheritance means the subclass should pass IS-A test for superclass and in your case, the list of cars is not exactly a car.

Comment: Thanks, the "IS-A" was the expression I was looking for - I'm preparing slides to describe why the code base is awful, so I'll add that.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, something about that feels wrong. In my mind a collection of `object`s shouldn't extend that `object` as well.

It may be the case that you have a Dealership that holds some cars, but I would think you would do that like (and I don't java so I might screw up the syntax a little):

```
class Dealership extends Businesses
{
    private private ArrayList<Car> sellableCars;

    public void itsAHugeSalesSpectacular() {
        for(Car car: sellableCars) car.Vrooom(); 
    }
}
```

But in my experience there is no reason that you'd define the cars of the dealership as an object in its own right.